# How can I trigger and bind to arbitrary events within a Chrome extension?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension, jquery-events

I have some code in a background script.  I want to be able to fire something like:

```
$(document).trigger('someEvent', [args]);
```

And then in a popup listen for it with something like this:

```
var backgroundPage = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
$(backgroundPage.document).bind('someEvent', function (args) {...});
```

But that doesn't work.  The trigger code gets triggered, but clearly I'm not binding to the right thing.  Help?

Comment: Why don't you used the dedicated [message passing](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html) module? With a simple addition you could support events as well.

Comment: 1. Is jQuery loaded in the popup *and* the background page? 2. Any inline JavaScript (if yes, read about [the CSP](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html)). 3. Are you binding the event *before* triggering? 3. Why are you using events when the same can be done in a non-convoluted way using functions? `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().customMethod();` and/or [`chrome.extension.getViews()`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#method-getViews).

Comment: Actually, @pimvdb, that's exactly where I did.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really know JQuery so Im no help there, but thought Id point out that it does seem to work the JS way....

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "TEST - Background to PopUp Event Triggering",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
      "default_title": "TEST - Background to PopUp Event Triggering",
      "default_icon": "icon.png",
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
   "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "manifest_version" : 2
}
```

**popup.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
var backgroundPage = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();

backgroundPage.document.addEventListener('myCustomEvent', function(e) {
    document.write(e.args + '\n');
})
```

**background.js**

```
var customEvent = document.createEvent('Event');
customEvent.initEvent('myCustomEvent', true, true);

setInterval(function() {
    customEvent.args=["bunyips","smell"];
    document.dispatchEvent(customEvent);
}, 3000);
```

Comment: Interesting.  Originally I was using jQuery to -- in theory -- do exactly what you have above.  It failed.  I guess jQuery could have been the culprit.